# $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^\frac{1}{n}= \frac{a^\frac{1}{n}}{b^\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem is to prove this for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ 
$$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^\frac{1}{n}= \frac{a^\frac{1}{n}}{b^\frac{1}{n}}$$
My attempt:
$$x=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^\frac{1}{n}$$
$$x^n=\frac{a}{b}$$
$$b\cdot x^n=a$$
$$b^{(\frac{1}{n})}\cdot x =a^\frac{1}{n}$$
$$x=\frac{a^\frac{1}{n}}{b^\frac{1}{n}}$$
But problem is that I in 4 line use what I need to prove.

Comment: I think you should be very careful to specify which axioms/theorems you're using at each step.

Comment: Theo is correct,  you should specify which axioms you used.

Answer (score 1):

Fourth line in error. It should be
$$b^{(\frac{1}{n})}\cdot x =a^{(\frac{1}{n})}$$
All else OK

Comment: Are you sure it will be ok?
Because in previous line $b\cdot x^n=a$
And I use $n$-th root
$(bx^n)^\frac{1}{n} = b^\frac{1}{n}\cdot x$

Comment: The same rule should be applied on both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I will give a you a simple proof.

Let $$x = a$$

Let $$y = \frac{1}{b}$$

Let $$z = \frac{1}{n}$$

Therefore your equation becomes $$(xy)^z = x^z * y^z ⇒ xy * xy * xy..... xy, ntimes = (x * x * x..... x, ntimes) * (y * y * y..... y, ntimes) $$ 
In this equation, LHS and RHS are equal due to commutativity of multiplication.